# Swift Import Obj-C Framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, tesseract

I am having trouble importing a Obj-C Framework into a Swift Project.

Beginning with an empty swift project here is everything I did:

- Drag and drop the  Tesseract framework into XCode (copy items if needed was checked)
- Drag and drop a random .m file into XCode

  - XCode generated a Bridging Header File for me
- Deleted random .m file, leaving bridging header file
- Added import statement to the bridging header file

I dont have enough reputation to add pictures but here are links to various parts of my project:

[Project File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFqlF.png)

[Project Build Phases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10Eud.png)

There is a single line of code in the **Bridging Header**:

```
#import <TesseractOCR/TesseractOCR.h>
```

In Build Settings the **Obj-C Bridging Header** setting is set to:

```
Swift OCR Test/Swift OCR Test-Bridging-Header.h
```

In Build Settings the **Framework Search Paths** setting is set to:

```
$(inherited) $(PROJECT_DIR)
```

I receieve a bunch of Apple Mach-O Linker Errors when I build the project.  Could someone offer a suggestion about how to get the project set up properly?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post what the linker errors are.  They're usually quite telling.

Comment: There are 51 errors all regarding the Tesseract Framework
[Screenshot of Linker Errors](http://i.imgur.com/GA4Aoph.png)

Comment: Where did you download the Tesseract library from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `libstdc++.dylib` to the Linked Frameworks and Libraries in the General tab for your project.

Comment: Everything was fixed when I added libstdc++.6.dylib
Thanks!